# POJO with slash in variable name conversion to JSON conversion using jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to use jackson to convert a pojo to json. 
The json that I need to generate has the following structure -

```
"paragraphs": [
  {
    "text": "This is a test text",
    "page/pages": "1/56",
  }
```

Notice how one of the items is "page/pages", but I cannot directly creating a variable name in POJO with the same name. How do I generate the JSON in the above format if slash is not allowed in variable name in java?

Comment: nevermind, I found the answer with jackson annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an annotation e.g.

```
@JsonProperty("page/pages")
public String pages;
```